# Ruby on Rails: How to change default color of a division/tag?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

In my Web application I want to change color of one tag, column header.

Currently it looks like:

```
%th= link_to  "Title"
```

How do I add property to change text background color?

Comment: %th{:style => "background-color: red;"}

Comment: @VaibhavDhoke: You can add the comment as answer, I will accept it as answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
%th{ style: 'background-color: red;' }
```

This is the simplest way you can do. Above answer is also one way of doing it.